# Simple multiple integral: Wolfram's answer won't match

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is the following definite integral not correct?

[image]

Wolfram's answer is $\frac{5}{6}$. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: $\int y\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{y^2}{2}+C$

Comment: First formula in second row, it should say $y^2/2$ in place of $y^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You integrated $\int y \ \mathrm{d}y = y^2$ instead of $\int y \ \mathrm{d}y = \frac 1 2 y^2$.